# Fastest way to find minimal product of 2 array elements containing 200000+ elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, minimum

I have an array `a[n]`. The number `n` is entered by us. I need to find the minimal product of `a[i]` and `a[j]` if:

1) `abs(i - j) > k`

2) `a[i] * a[j]` is minimised

Here is my solution (very naive):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long
int main() {
    ll n,k; cin >> n >> k;

    ll a[n]; for(ll i=0;i<n;i++) cin >> a[i];

    ll mn; bool first = true;

    for(ll i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(ll j=0;j<n;j++) {
            if(i!=j)
            if(abs(i-j) > k) {
                if(first) {
                    mn = a[i]*a[j];
                    first = false;
                } else if(a[i]*a[j] < mn) mn = a[i]*a[j];
            }
        }
    }
    cout << mn << endl;
}
```

But I want to know if there is any faster way to find a minimal product with distance?

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h/31816096) and C++ only provide a *Variable Length Array* by compiler extension. Why are you not using `std::vector`? @Scheff - sorting would destroy the original "distance" relationships.

Comment: At least the check `if (i!=j) if (abs(i - j) > k)` can be eliminated. Just start the inner loop at i + k + 1: `for (ll j = i + k + 1; j < n; ++j)`. The check with `first` can be eliminated as well if `mn` is initialized prior e.g. with `mn = a[0] * a[k + 1];`. (Maybe, `k` should be checked against `n` initially to make this bullet-proof.) But it's still O(N²). This must be doable faster...

Comment: are there negative numbers in your array ?

Comment: @lenik Do you think negative numbers in the array make a difference?

Comment: @Scheff when you multiply two very small negative numbers the result becomes a very large positive number. so the sorting stops working properly.

Comment: I guess it can be done in O(2N) (which is effectively O(N)): 1. Linear search for the minimal number in array. 2. Linear search for the second minimal number, starting at index of first + k + 1 and checking for difference to first as well. Finally, multiply both found numbers.

Comment: @Scheff if you sort the array and multiply `a[0] * a[1]` -- this won't be the smallest product in case there are negative numbers.

Comment: @lenik Damn, I forgot that the product of two negatives is positive...

Comment: @lenik So, in this case if the first found is negative, the search for the second must be turned into searching for maximum positive? (I'm afraid I shouldn't continue to puzzle before having had a cup of coffee...)

Comment: @Scheff yeah... the proximity limitations might easily weed out the N smallest numbers, because they are too close to each other. So, once you sort, you still have to traverse the array, which kind of defies the purpose.

Comment: @lenik I discarded the idea with sort a while ago... ;-)

Comment: *But I want to know if there is any faster way to find minimal product with distance?* -- There are probably hundreds, if not thousands of URL links that shows answers to this question.

Comment: @Scheff why is that? make a `std::pair<float, int>( number, position )`, sort away and have fun! =)

Comment: Well, the @OP asked, and one answer could be "use google".  @OP -- `ll a[n];` --don't do this.  First, this is not valid C++ .  Second, even it were valid, the stack memory will more than likely not be able to hold such an array.

Comment: @lenik This is something which I considered as well. But for large input data it will result in double large intermediate data...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Please show *one* query with no less than two *useful* hits among the first ten for *minimal product with index distance* (or maximal).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie "There are probably hundreds, if not thousands of URL links that shows answers to this question." -- please share at least three of these URLs.

Comment: Where did this question come from?  It does not sound like something just made up out of thin air.  I wouldn't be surprised if it is from one of those "online judge" sites.  If so, on those sites are probably long drawn-out discussions on solving the problem, if not full solutions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming there is at least one pair of elements satisfying the conditions and no multiplication of two elements in it overflows, this can be done in `Theta(n-k)` time and `Theta(1)` space worst- and best-case, with something like this:

```
auto back_max = a[0];
auto back_min = a[0];
auto best = a[0]*a[k+1];

for(std::size_t i=1; i<n-(k+1); ++i) {
    back_max = std::max(back_max, a[i]);
    back_min = std::min(back_min, a[i]);
    best = std::min(best, std::min(a[i+k+1]*back_max, a[i+k+1]*back_min));
}

return best;
```

This is optimal in terms of asymptotic worst-case complexity for both time and space because the optimal product may be `a[0]` with any of the `n-(k+1)` elements in distance at least `k+1`, so at least `n-(k+1)` integers need to be read by any algorithm solving the problem.

---

The idea behind the algorithm is as follows:

The optimal product uses two elements of `a`, assume these are `a[r]` and `a[s]`. Without loss of generality we can assume that `s > r` since the product is commutative.

Due to the restriction `abs(s-r) > k` this implies that `s >= k+1`. Now `s` could be each of the indices satisfying this condition, so we iterate over these indices. That is the iteration over `i` in the shown code, but it is  shifted by `k+1` for convenience (doesn't really matter). For each iteration we need to find the optimal product involving `i+k+1` as largest index and compare it with the previous best guess.

The possible indices to pair `i+k+1` with are all indices smaller or equal `i` due to the distance requirement. We would need to iterate over all of these as well, but that is unnecessary because the minimum of `a[i+k+1]*a[j]` over `j` at fixed `i` is equal to `min(a[i+k+1]*max(a[j]), a[i+k+1]*min(a[j]))` due to monotonicity of the product (taking the minimum with respect to both the minimum and maximum over `a[j]` accounts for the two possible signs of `a[i+k+1]` or equivalently the two possible directions of monotonicity.)

Since the set of `a[j]` values over which we optimize here is just `{a[0], ..., a[i]}`, which simply growths by one element (`a[i]`) in each iteration of `i`, we can simply keep track of `max(a[j])` and `min(a[j])` with single variables by updating them if `a[i]` is larger or smaller than the previous optimal values. This is done with `back_max` and `back_min` in the code example.

The first step of the iteration (`i=0`) is skipped in the loop and instead performed as initialization of the variables.

Comment: @greybeard I don't need to keep them around, because the only possible candidates for an optimal product with `a[i+k+1]` are the minimum and maximum.

Comment: could you explain why the algorithm works in your answer?

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about *fastest*.

For the simpler problem without *i < j - k*, the minimal product is among the products of pairs from the two smallest and largest elements.

So, (the following is too complicated, see [walnut's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59701925))
( • balk if k ≤ n
  • initialise minProduct to a[0]*a[k+1])

- keep two [dynamic minmax data structures](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_priority_queue) *upToI* and *beyondIplusK*
  starting with { } and { a[*j*] | *k* ≤ *j* }
- for each *i* from 0 to *n* - *k* - 1

  - add a[*i*] to *upToI*
  - remove a[*i*+*k*] from *beyondIplusK*
  - check for new minimal product among
    min(*upToI*)×min(*beyondIplusK*), min(*upToI*)×max(*beyondIplusK*),
    max(*upToI*)×min(*beyondIplusK*) and max(*upToI*)×max(*beyondIplusK*)

Comment: This should be the fastest, at least complexity-wise. It is O(n) time and storage.

Comment: the original solution has the complexity O(N**2), how do you estimate the complexity of your solution ?

Comment: O(nlogn) time, O(n) space (for suitable minmax implementations)

Comment: @greybeard. Why do you need n*logn time. Why not simply keeping a 4*n array that contains `minUpto`, `maxUpto`, `minBeyond`, `maxBeyond` (You can create in two iterations)? Then, in the third iteration, for each index, find the min possible multiplication.

Comment: (@smttsp That would be an alternative step in the direction of [walnut's *solution*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59701925).)

Answer (score 4):

**For "minimum magnitude"**

Find the 2 "smallest magnitude" elements, then (after you've either found two zeros or searched the whole array), multiply them.

**For "lowest value" without the `abs(i - j) > k` part**

There are 3 possibilities:

- the two highest (smallest magnitude) negative numbers
- the two lowest (smallest magnitude) non-negative numbers
- the lowest (largest magnitude) negative number and the highest (largest magnitude) non-negative number

You could search for all 6 values and figure out the products and which is best at end.

However; as soon as you see a zero you know you don't need to know any more about the first 2 possibilities; and as soon as you see one negative number and one non-negative number you know that you only care about the third possibility.

This leads to a finite state machine with 3 states - "care about all 3 possibilities", "answer is zero unless a negative number is seen" and "only care about the last possibility". This can be implemented as a set of 3 loops, where 2 of the loops jump into (`goto`) the middle of another loop when the state (of the finite state machine) changes.

Specifically, it might looks something vaguely like (untested):

```
   // It could be any possibility

   for(ll i=0;i<n;i++) {
       if(a[i] >= 0) {
            if(a[i] < lowestNonNegative1) {
                lowestNonNegative2 = lowestNonNegative1;
                lowestNonNegative1 = a[i];
            }
            if(lowestNonNegative2 == 0) {
                goto state2;
            }
       } else {
            if(a[i] > highestNegative1) {
                highestNegative2 = highestNegative1;
                highestNegative1= a[i];
            }
            if(lowestNonNegative1 < LONG_MAX) {
                goto state3;
            }
       }
   }
   if(lowestNonNegative2 * lowestNonNegative1 < highestNegative2 * highestNegative1) {
       cout << lowestNonNegative2 * lowestNonNegative1;
   } else {
       cout << highestNegative2 * highestNegative1;
   }
   return;

   // It will be zero, or a negative and a non-negative

   for(ll i=0;i<n;i++) {
state2:
       if(a[i] < 0) {
           goto state3;
       }
   }
   cout << "0";
   return;

   // It will be a negative and a non-negative

   for(ll i=0;i<n;i++) {
state3:
       if(a[i] < lowestNegative) {
           lowestNegative = a[i];
       } else if(a[i] > highestNonNegative) {
           highestNonNegative = a[i];
       }
    }
    cout << lowestNegative * highestNonNegative;
    return;
```

**For "lowest value" with the `abs(i - j) > k` part**

In this case you still have the 3 possibilities; and could make it work with the same "3 loops with finite state machine" approach but it gets too messy/ugly. For this case a better alternative is likely to pre-scan the array to determine if there are any zeros and if they're all negative or all positive; so that after the pre-scan you can either know the answer is zero or select a loop designed for the specific possibility alone.

Comment: Where does this account for the lower bound *k* on index difference?

Comment: @greybeard: It doesn't (I missed that part) - code would need to be modified to take that into account.

Comment: Why would you need *two* zeros?

Comment: @TrentP: Argh - you're right. One zero is enough to know the answer is either 0 or a negative number.